# trap not working in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, process

I'm in the process of writing a script on OS X that needs to trap SIGTERM in order to kill some child processes before exiting.  For the sake of this question I've boiled it down to the following minimal example that, for some reason, isn't working as I'd expect it to:

```
#!/bin/sh

function shutdown()
{
  touch foo.txt
  exit 0
}

trap shutdown TERM
su -l myusername -c "sleep 9999"
```

I run this script in one terminal window, then switch to another and "ps -aef" yields this:

```
  502   857   645   0 11:38PM ttys001    0:00.00 /bin/sh ./foo.sh
    0   858   857   0 11:38PM ttys001    0:00.02 su -l myusername -c sleep 9999
  502   859   858   0 11:38PM ttys001    0:00.00 sleep 9999
```

From that second window I then issue "kill -15 857", but the trap is never triggered.  The script remains blocked on the "su" command.

Any idea why?  I get the feeling it's something simple.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [bash manual states](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Signals.html#Signals) that:

> If  bash  is  waiting for a command to complete and receives a signal
>   for which a trap has been set, the trap will not be executed until the
>   command completes.

As [gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf) says, this is a POSIX spec relative to [signals in shells](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_11).

You can check it by trapping for instance SIGUSR1 in place of SIGTERM; you'll see that `kill -TERM` will kill again the process.

A solution is to run the command in background, then `wait` for its termination. In this case the `trap` will work. Try this:

```
#! /bin/bash

shutdown()
{
    touch foo.txt
    exit 0
}

trap shutdown TERM
su -l myusername -c "sleep 9999" &    # On Ubuntu: sudo su
wait
```

You will get two problems: `su` won't be able to ask password in foreground; you will have to manually kill `su`.

Comment: Good answer. Though this is not relevant to Bash only, it's specified by POSIX too: see [Section 2.11 _Signals_ in the POSIX specs‌](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html)​. I'm specifying this because OP has `#!/bin/sh` shebang. But you're right, with `su` it becomes irrelevant.

Comment: I am planning to use shutdown() to kill all child processes spawned by this script.  It will be called by launchd.  Calling this script, as opposed to having launchd just run the command as myusername, was necessary because apparently setting the user in the launchd plist isn't enough to allow the Mac "security" command to do some of the keychain-related things I need it to do.  This seems to only work when I simulate an actual login, hence su.  launchctl will only send a SIGTERM to my script, though, and not its child processes, so I have to clean them up myself.

Comment: Side question: do you know a clean way of getting the PID of the command launched by "su" back into the calling script?  That is, the PID of "sleep 9999"?

Comment: `pidof sleep` is a solution, but only if there is one `sleep` running at that time... or, try: `pidof sleep | grep 9999`

Comment: Looks like I either need to do something like this:

http://serverfault.com/questions/376086/how-to-get-the-pid-of-a-process-started-by-bin-su-c

...or generate a random string in the launching script and pass it as a dummy parameter to the command, then use pgrep in shutdown() to find the right PID.  That would avoid having to write the PID to a file.

Comment: Oh, also, regarding su / sudo, by default launchd will run the script as root so I don't have to worry about passwords.