# How do I make sure a process launched by Docker entrypoint can be killed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker, entry-point

I'm building a Docker image that launches a long-running Java process. I want to make sure that it can be killed together with the container (e.g. by using Ctrl+C) yet still perform cleanup.

If I'm using `exec java -jar` in my entrypoint, it works as expected.
If I'm simply executing `java -jar`, the process cannot be killed.

However `exec` makes the container exit even on success, and that is a problem if this command is not the last one in the entrypoint. For example, if some file conversion or cleanup follows, it will not get executed:

```
exec java -jar "./lib/Saxon-HE-${SAXON_VER}.jar" -s:"$json_xml" -xsl:"$STYLESHEET" base-uri="$base"
rm "$json_xml"
```

I think the explanation is that using `exec` the process (`java` in this case) becomes PID=1 and receives the kill signals, while without `exec` it gets some other PID and does not receive the signals and therefore can't be killed.

So my question is two-fold:

- is there a workaround that allows the process to be killed without exiting the container on success as `exec` does?
- how do I make sure the cleanup after `exec` (`rm` in this case) gets executed even if the process is killed/exits?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an entrypoint bash script that traps the CTRL-C signal, kills (or gracefully stops?) the java process and does your cleanup afterwards.

Example (not tested):

```
#!/bin/bash

# trap ctrl-c and call ctrl_c()
trap ctrl_c INT

function ctrl_c() {
        echo "Trapped CTRL-C"
        # Do something here. Kill Java?
}

java -jar "./lib/Saxon-HE-${SAXON_VER}.jar" -s:"$json_xml" -xsl:"$STYLESHEET" base-uri="$base"
```

Add it to your docker image and make it your entrypoint

```
FROM java:8

ADD docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: I've tried this, it doesn't work because bash does not propagate signals to child processes (which is what `java` becomes without `exec`).

I think https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444676 might be related, but I haven't wrapped my head around the solution yet.

Comment: You can send the signal to the java process by using kill after bash traps it. You should also trap SIGTERM as well which is what `docker stop` and `docker restart` sends to the container.

Comment: I'm trying this now, but Ctrl+C has no effect -- Java process continues.

Comment: Which signal are you sending to the java process ? Because this sounds like the java application you are executing doesn't listen for the signal you are sending or is just ignoring it.

Comment: If I launch it directly from shell using `java -jar` (no Docker whatsoever) Ctrl+C kills it immediately, as expected. What is the difference then?

Comment: If your entrypoint doesn't have the brackets then docker executes it by doing /bin/sh -c "command", the /bin/sh will receive the SIGINT signal and not your entrypoint

Comment: I setup up the trap successfully, but it is only executed _after_ `java` completes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26865972/1003113
So I don't think I can kill Java in a trap if a trap waits for Java to complete?

Answer (score 1):

I use tini. Here is the reference [link](https://github.com/krallin/tini)

Comment: Thanks, looks promising. Does it help with the cleanup?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I added `ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "--", "/usr/src/gmail-trix-exporter/entrypoint.sh"]` but the `java` process invoked by `entrypoint.sh` still cannot be killed using Ctrl+C.

Answer (score 1):

You can just build another program which will manage the java child process and the cleanup, for example using the same `java`, `go` or `rust` to write such. I'm sure these languages have a proper process control tools and you can catch the CTRL-C and other events to stop the internal child process and do the cleanup. Probably it would even take less time compared to searching for the tools which will have limited behavior anyways. Also it may be even worth to open source it for such problems.

Comment: I went for this solution, wrote a bash script.